# How to achieve JWT authentication between nuxt 3 (vue.js) frontend, Symfony 4 backend and remote app where the users are stored?

Tags: php, jwt, symfony4

I have a Nuxt 3 (vue.js) frontend that has to authenticate using JWT users with Symfony 4 backend. The users are actually stored in a 3rd app that has an API to which Symfony has to make a request each time a user is authenticated. So basically the workflow is:

1. The user submits their email and password in the frontend.
2. The frontend sends the data to the Symfony 4 backend.
3. The Symfony 4 backend makes an API call to a remote app sending the username and the
   password in the request.
4. The remote app sends a confirmation to Symfony 4
5. Symfony 4 generate the JWT and returns it to the frontend
6. The user authenticates in the frontend and the requests are then sent only to Symfony 4 via the frontend

In Symfony 4 I am already using the LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle and my research led me to the moment when I have to create my own user provider and also create a custom authenticator.

From what I read I have to hook up to the checkCredentials function and in it, I should execute the API request to the third app.

Am I on the right road or there is a much simpler way to do this?

P.S. Please don't ask me why I do not hook the frontend to the 3rd app and skip Symfony.

Comment: I hope it's OK to add a question as a comment. I'm trying to code an authentication from Nuxt 3, using $fetch, to a custom separate API using JWT without using any auth module. But I can't find any documentation and don't know how to start. If you could share all your current configuration (specifying files name/path as well), I'll be really grateful! Thx!

Comment: My question was more oriented to Symfony 4, actually. I managed to find a solution by encoding/decoding the JWT in Symfony 4 outside of the LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle. Without the auth module, basically what you want to do is to store the JWT in the local storage of the client and send it with each request from nuxt to the backend. The backend will then verify the token and handle your logic. Of course do not forget to check for the jwt validity and expiration in the jwt verification stage on the backend.

Comment: Thanks @Simeon Mitev for your feedback, really appreciated it!